# Find the Fourier series representation of $f(t)=\sin(3\pi t)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Find the Fourier series representation of

$$f(x)=\sin(3\pi t)\qquad \text{for }-1\leq t\leq1$$

When I calculate the coefficients, I always get $0$. Why is that? Is the series indeed zero?

Comment: Which Fourier series are you looking for? As in: exponential, sine or cosine

Comment: The coefficients of the cosine terms are zero since $\;f(x)\;$ is odd.

Comment: The general one  $$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl[a_n \cos(nx) +b_n \sin(nx)\biggl]$$ When I compute  I get all $a_0$, $a_n$ and  $b_n$ zero why?

Comment: What is the formula you're using to compute $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: I used the formulas from [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FourierSeries.aspx)

Comment: The answer below is formally correct, but it would be better to recognize that $\sin (3\pi t)$ is *already* a Fourier series, where one coefficient is $1$ and the rest are $0$. There is nothing to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general Fourier series 
\begin{align}
f(x) = A_{0} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( A_{n} \, \cos\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) + B_{n} \, \sin\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \right)
\end{align}
where the coefficients are 
\begin{align}
A_{0} &= \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \, dx \\
A_{n} &= \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \, \cos\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \, dx \\
B_{n} &= \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \, \sin\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \, dx
\end{align}
leads to, for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $f(x) = \sin(3 \pi x)$, the following.
\begin{align}
A_{0} &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \sin(3 \pi x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \left[ - \frac{\cos(3 \pi x)}{3 \pi} \right]_{-1}^{1} = 0 \\
A_{n} &= \int_{-1}^{1} \sin(3 \pi x) \, \cos(n \pi x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \, \left[\frac{\cos(\pi (n-3) x))}{n-3} - \frac{cos(\pi (n+3) x))}{n+3} \right]_{-1}^{1} 
\end{align}
If $n \neq 3$ then the value of this is zero. For the case of $n=3$ it is seen that
\begin{align}
A_{3} &= \int_{-1}^{1} \sin(3\pi x) \, \cos(3\pi x) \, dx = - \frac{1}{12 \pi} \left[ \cos(6 \pi x) \right]_{-1}^{1} = 0.
\end{align}
The remaining coefficients are 
\begin{align}
B_{n \neq 3} &= \int_{-1}^{1} \sin(3 \pi x) \sin(n \pi x) \, dx = - \frac{6 \, \sin(n \pi)}{\pi (n^{2} -9)}
\end{align}
which is zero for $n$ being an integer. The last term is
\begin{align}
B_{3} = \int_{-1}^{1} \sin^{2}(3\pi x) \, dx = 1.
\end{align}
The Fourier series is then given by
\begin{align}
\sin(3 \pi x) = \sin(3 \pi x)
\end{align}